# Antd source map not supported in React

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, antd, cra

I have an issue regarding the integration of Ant Design library in a CRA (create-react-app).

After I have tried to integrate it as it is required in their [documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app), without integration of Craco, I always get these 4 warnings:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/config-provider/style/index.less' URL is not supported
 @ ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css 8:6-231 22:17-24 26:7-21 58:25-39 59:36-47 59:50-64 61:4-74:5 63:6-73:7 64:54-65 64:68-82 70:42-53 70:56-70 72:21-28 83:0-201 83:0-201 84:22-29 84:33-47 84:50-64
 @ ./src/components/pages/app/App.tsx 10:0-28
 @ ./src/components/index.ts 3:0-34 4:15-18
 @ ./src/index.tsx 6:0-31 8:38-41

WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/icon/style/index.less' URL is not supported
 @ ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css 8:6-231 22:17-24 26:7-21 58:25-39 59:36-47 59:50-64 63:6-73:7 64:54-65 64:68-82 70:42-53 70:56-70 72:21-28 83:0-201 83:0-201 84:22-29 84:33-47 84:50-64 61:4-74:5
 @ ./src/components/pages/app/App.tsx 10:0-28
 @ ./src/components/index.ts 3:0-34 4:15-18
 @ ./src/index.tsx 6:0-31 8:38-41

WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/locale-provider/style/index.less' URL is not supported
 @ ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css 8:6-231 22:17-24 26:7-21 58:25-39 59:36-47 59:50-64 63:6-73:7 64:54-65 64:68-82 70:42-53 70:56-70 72:21-28 83:0-201 83:0-201 84:22-29 84:33-47 84:50-64 61:4-74:5
 @ ./src/components/pages/app/App.tsx 10:0-28
 @ ./src/components/index.ts 3:0-34 4:15-18
 @ ./src/index.tsx 6:0-31 8:38-41

WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/time-picker/style/index.less' URL is not supported
 @ ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css 8:6-231 22:17-24 26:7-21 58:25-39 59:36-47 59:50-64 63:6-73:7 64:54-65 64:68-82 70:42-53 70:56-70 72:21-28 83:0-201 83:0-201 84:22-29 84:33-47 84:50-64 61:4-74:5
 @ ./src/components/pages/app/App.tsx 10:0-28
 @ ./src/components/index.ts 3:0-34 4:15-18
 @ ./src/index.tsx 6:0-31 8:38-41
```

I use the following versions:

```
"antd": "^4.19.2",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "5.0.0",
```

Can someone help me regarding this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This problem occurred after react-script was upgraded to 5.0.0
solution :

```js
- import 'antd/dist/antd.css
```

replace with :

```
+ import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css
```

Answer (score 10):

Though, I succeeded in eliminating the errors only by integrating CRACO and LESS. Changing in `src/App.tsx`:

```
- import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
+ import '~antd/dist/antd.less';
```

So, from what I see, the issue may be with the `import '~antd/dist/antd.css';`, imported in `src/App.tsx`.

Comment: this saved us from lots of warnings after months!

Comment: This solution is for when you're using less, look at the solutions below for css https://stackoverflow.com/a/72111591/9521924

Answer (score 5):

The previous solution did not work for me, because although it was removing the compilation error it was breaking all the Antd styles of the app.

We found this solution instead:

> import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css'

From [this Chinese site](https://blog.csdn.net/FenceRain/article/details/123463036).

A more customized solution would be to use [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra)

Actually it is also solved in [the issues of their repo!](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/33327)

Comment: worked for me in Oct 2022 -> "antd": "^4.23.4",

Answer (score 3):

**Replacing** this all work for me:

```
 - import 'antd/dist/antd.css
```

**replace with :**

```
+ import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css
```

Answer (score 2):

in app.tsx use import "antd/dist/antd.min.css"; to replace import "antd/dist/antd.css";

Answer (score 1):

after spending much time on fixing this,,
i found that adding `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to your .env file will remove the error.

it is said that this is caused by Webpack 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing this issue with react-scripts/cra version 5.0.0. You'll need to add the following to your .env file

GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false

or you can update your script to

"start": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts start",
Note: this is a temporary patch until 5.0.1 is released. See create-react-app repo pull request Update: 5.0.1 was release on April 2022. Changelog. The update did not fix this issue. Not sure when that will be ‍♂️

By: [roger-perez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6064543/roger-perez)

Comment: it works but is there any downside to not GENERATE_SOURCEMAP?

Comment: @JaydipSapariya Severely degraded debugging capability. It will drop into the total gibberish minified generated output, not your nice readable source code, in the debugger. The source map remembers what source is to blame for chunks of generated output. Your browser dev tools use it to backtrack to your source, and it indicates your code in that, instead of showing the generated gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

Use import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css instead of import 'antd/dist/antd.css in your app.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Vite+React. And I use this

```
import "antd/dist/reset.css";
```

It works.
My Package Version:

```
"vite": "^4.3.2"
"antd": "^5.4.7",
```